# Sum varchar field in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a Varchar field for gross, the field has something like $1,000, $190, $2,900

I need to sum this column, should I alter the column to INT? and then use a regex to remove the $? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix the database so numbers are stored as numbers, not as strings.  But, to do the sum, you can try:

```
select sum(replace(replace(gross, ',', ''), '$', '') + 0)
```

This will convert your examples to a number and add them up.  If something is in a different format, it will silently produce a `0` for that value.

By the way, "gross" is an apt name for a field varchar field containing a number.